# How can I list all *.doc files in a Zip archive, including files in subdirectories?

Tags: wildcards, recursive, zip

I have Zip files, that might look like this:

```
$ zipinfo -1 zip.zip
doc.doc
dotx.dotx
xls.xls
ppt.ppt
txt.txt
c.c
subdir/subdir2/doc.doc
subdir/xls.xls
subdir/ppt.ppt
subdir/c.c
subdir/txt.txt
subdir/subdir2/
subdir/
```

I want it to print all the *.doc files, but `zipinfo -1 zip.zip *.doc` only prints the .doc files in the root directory of the Zip file.  How can I print all the .doc files, in all the subdirectories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
zipinfo -1 zip.zip '*.doc'
```

works for me, displaying all files in sub-directories. I think you are forgetting the quotes around the `*.doc`. Without the quotes, the `*.doc` expands to all `.doc` files in the current directory, and then that is passed to zipinfo as the search pattern. So if you have an unzipped version of the archive present in the local directory, then the command will only show top-level `.doc` files.

With quotes, the argument is protected from the shell, so the wildcard actually makes it to `zipinfo` successfully.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one:

```
zipinfo -1 zip.zip | grep '\(/\|^\)*.\.doc$'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mount the archive as a directory, you can use the usual commands without having to worry about the fact that the files are inside an archive.

The [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) filesystem presents a view of the filesystem where every archive file `/path/to/foo.zip` is accessible as a directory `~/.avfs/path/to/foo.zip#`. AVFS provides read-only access to most common archive file formats. Run the command

```
mountavfs
```

once after each reboot (if you ever want to unmount `~/.avfs`, run `fusermount -u ~/.avfs`).

After that, the usual commands will work:

```
cd ~/.avfs$PWD
find zip.zip\# -name '*.doc'
```

or

```
ls ~/.avfs$PWD/zip.zip\#/**/*.doc
```